# How can I ready/start the page from the center instead of top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i would like to do some animation in my website main page, when it's open/ready, to start from the center of the page then goes up smoothly to the top in JavaScript or HTML or CSS ? (i'm looking for the easiest simplest way)

Comment: Have you considered using some readily available libraries such as [wow](https://wowjs.uk/) or [animate](https://animate.style/)?

Comment: In the 4 years you rarely using SO, the guidelines still didnt change. Your question does not meet the guidelines as it can be considered opinion based and does not contain a specific coding issue. its mere conceptional as you did not attempt to solve it on your own first (or at least gave no notion of it). Also I will claim that you did not spend any research efford. For your solution you either looking at anchors or offsets. SO and the web is full of tutorials for it.

Comment: @tacoshy first of all, what's your problem!!. secondly i'm still a beginner specially with JavaScript and it's all libraries. so i was just asking (the nice people here {not you} ) what's the best simplest way to do such a thing cuz i have no idea. after that i would search and learn about it more and more maybe. btw i'm new here

Comment: well your account is 4 years old, so I do not consider you as new. Its ok to be a beginner, still you questions does not meet the SO guidelines which I pointing out. I'm sorry that you feel offended by that, but SO has clear guidelines which questions can be asked and how they can be asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small example for you using `scrollIntoView ()`, on `jquery`. Also, set `setTimeout()` to delay before scrolling to the top of the page.

This is not a perfect solution, as I did it with a hastily :) But you can improve my solution.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {

  $("body")[0].scrollIntoView({
    block: "center"
  });
  
  setTimeout(function(){
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000)
  }, 3000);
  
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```